# Image downsampling by a fraction

Tags: imageprocessing, psd, power-spectral-density

I need to downsample an image (bitmap image of a Spectrogram) by a fraction, N/D, (rational: ex 4/5). I understand that this can be done with resampling by 4 followed by decimation by 5. If this is true, is there a more efficient way in this case, more efficient == computationally faster)?

Also, following the above, I will need to generated the Power Spectral Density (PSD) for the image, I believe, being a Waterfall image, I will do this for each new row of frequency info of the image, does this sound correct?
Thanks...

Comment: Sure there are more efficent ways but they come with downsides. Just skip 1 pixel after copying 4. But you will lose data. But what does this has to do with electronics?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of scientific papers looking at efficient algorithms for image resampling. So yes, probably many are faster than the specific one you're using. How fast do you need? How accurate do you require?

Comment: Look up polyphase FIR resampling filters. They work faster than naive resampling/decimation, by not computing anything that's going to be thrown away later. Use the smallest kernel that gives the accuracy you need. Lanczos is a standard reasonably-performing image filter.

Comment: FYI, it is always a good idea to add dither when downsampling to avoid quantization artifacts and Mach bands. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_bands